# Start and Immediately Close application without showing Form

Tags: c#

I have a very simple GUI application in C# and there is some codes in Form Load function. I just want to start and close the application without showing Form for running those codes in form load function.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you could try to create a service which contains no GUIs

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to show a form, you should move your code to the `Main()` method and get rid of the form.

Comment: then it will show a black Console Screen at start up !

Comment: Only if you have it as a console application.

Comment: @Stranger: Change it to a Windows Application in Project Properties.

Answer (score 0):

form.Opacity = 0;

I am not sure if this is what you want.

EDIT: - This will keep form opaque and you can run and close it when an event occur.